# MySQL group count by 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Given** a `payments` table that includes `payer_id` and `recipient_id`

**And** calculating received payments would be:

```
select COUNT(*) as payer_count, recipient_id
FROM payments
GROUP BY recipient_id
ORDER BY payer_count DESC
```

**how do you calculate:** the number of payments that a user is on(a user can be either a payer_id or a recipient_id)?

Comment: Please explain your requirement in plain English. `count(either payer_id or recipient_id)` is meaningless syntax.

Comment: You are given a fixed ID and want to count in how many rows in payments it appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is suppose that you want to count - for every person with a particular id - the number of payment transactions in which this person has been involved, then a union all should help:

```sql
select person_id, count(*)
from ((select payer_id as person_id from payments) union all (select recipient_id as person_id from payments)) paymentsOfPerson
group by person_id
order by person_id DESC
```

If payments can also contain records where payer_id = recipient_id (transfer from one account to another account of the same person), then one has to take care that such transfers are not counted twice:

```sql
select person_id, count(*)
from ((select payer_id as person_id from payments where payer_id != recepient_id) union all (select recipient_id as person_id from payments)) paymentsOfPerson
group by person_id
order by person_id DESC
```

Comment: the first one! `UNION` ftw

Answer (score 0):

One method is `UNION ALL` before the aggregation:

```
select id, count(*) as cnt, sum(recipient) as recipient_cnt,
      sum(payer) as payer_cnt
from ((select recipient_id as id, 1 as recipient, 0 as payer
       from payments
      ) union all
      (select payer_id, 0, 1
       from payments
      )
     ) i
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as payments_count
    , COUNT(DISTINCT payer_id) distinct_payers
    , recipient_id
 FROM payments
GROUP BY recipient_id
ORDER BY payer_count DESC
```